# "The name 'sources' does not exist in the current context [Assembly-CSharp]",

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, audio-source

"The name 'sources' does not exist in the current context [Assembly-CSharp]",

Help! (unity 2017.3.0f3)

Here's the code:

```
public static SoundManager Instance = null;

public AudioClip goalBloop;
public AudioClip lossBuzz;
public AudioClip hitPaddleBloop;
public AudioClip winSound;
public AudioClip wallBloop;

private AudioSource soundEffectAudio;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    if(Instance == null)
    {
        Instance = this;
    } else if (Instance != this)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    AudioSource[] source = GetComponents<AudioSource>();

    foreach(AudioSource source in sources)
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typed sources in foreach statement , instead of source (declared here: `AudioSource[] source = GetComponents<AudioSource>();`).
You have declared source but are using sources that is the cause of the error.